# I want to ADD the data in the datagridview not create a new one

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox4.Text = textBox3.Text;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlstring);
        con.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT productid, name, ListPrice as Price FROM Production.Product where 
                      ProductID = @productid";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@productid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close();
    }
```

I want to add new rows not delete the previus and then add new
sqlstring is a const initialized at start
I don't know what the last 4 rows do but they used them in a tutorial i saw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last four lines means fill data from SqlDataAdapter object called **da** into newly empty created DataTable object called **dt**. After that set this filled object called **dt** into **dataGridView2** as it's data source using DataGridView.DataSource property. After that it is calling upon object **cmd** function Dispose which releases any resources that object is using for e.g memory consumed by this object. Finally you close connection to sql server.

Try modifying your code like this :

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox4.Text = textBox3.Text;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlstring);
        con.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT productid, name, ListPrice as Price FROM Production.Product where 
                      ProductID = @productid";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@productid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        
        DataTable dtOrig = ((DataTable)dataGridView2.DataSource);
         
        if(dtOrig != null)
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
            
            foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                  dtOrig.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        else
        {
             da.Fill(dt);
             dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
        }

        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Note this is not best solution how you should closing connection or using dispose function because every click on that button is connecting SQL server and it's database .Same for disconnect, but for purpose of learning it is fine. Best would be if you connect your databse in constructor and disconnect in destructor where functions Dispose and Close will be called. If you choose to do it in this way **cmd** object and **con** object should be defined at class scope as fields of class (so somewhere above constructor but inside of class).